# Error with using PdhAddEnglishCounter

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, pdh

My code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <Pdh.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "pdh.lib")
void main()
{
    PDH_STATUS Status;
    HQUERY Query = NULL;
    HCOUNTER Counter;
    WCHAR buffer[PDH_MAX_COUNTER_PATH];
    PdhOpenQuery(NULL, NULL, &Query);
    wcscpy(buffer, L"\\NTO-PROG\Thread(_Total/_Total)\Context Switches/sec");
    Status = PdhAddEnglishCounter(Query, buffer, 0, &Counter);
}
```

I have this error:

[image: pdh error]

English translate:

> Access point in procedure PdhAddEnglishCounterA not found in library DLL pdh.dll.

If i'm using `PdhAddCounter` instead of `PdhAddEnglishCounter`, i see in `Status`: `0xC0000BC0 (PDH_CSTATUS_BAD_COUNTERNAME)`. What I need to do with this?

p.s. I'm using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows XP.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for your error, [as MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa372536%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is that `PdhAddEnglishCounter` is not supported on Windows XP

[image]

For `PdhAddCounter`, the counter path has to be correctly localized. [Refer to MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa373193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You might want to consider `PdhLookupPerfNameByIndex` as an alternative (again, [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372648%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

There is a useful [article on the MS Knowledgebase](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;287159&x=11&y=9) too.